# 1+1D Bosonization on a line segment or a compact ring

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, topology

I have been informed that **1+1D Bosonization/Fermionization on a line segment** or **1+1D Bosonization/Fermionization a compact ring** are different -

Although I know that Bosonization can rewrite fermions in the non-local expression of bosons. But:

> bosons and fermions are fundamentally different for the case of on a 1D compact ring.

Is this true? How is the Bosonization/Fermionization different on **a line segment** or **a compact ring**? Does it matter whether the **line segment** is finite $x\in[a,b]$ or infinite $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$? Why? Can someone explain it physically? Thanks!

Comment: I think, when people say line segment, they often mean an interval $[a,b]$. Regarding your question, my low-brow understanding is that the difference has to do with  braiding. You cannot braid two (hard-core) bosons or fermions on a line segment, but you can on a ring. On a slightly more technical level, an example would be the Jordan-Wigner transformation for hard-core bosons. We need to be careful about boundary conditions when we do JW transformation on a ring.

Comment: Very good, Isidore, it totally makes sense.